# Retries in aws lambda for External API timeout

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, timeout

I have a aws lambda function which is invoked by API Gateway. The Lambda function calls external API endpoints and it sometime receives network time out while calling external API.
What is the best way to implement retry mechanism in aws lambda to handle network time out or other server side errors? Also is it good to use retry inside lambda function, which cost as per execution time?
Any recommendation is highly appreciated.
Regards

Answer (score 1):

> What is the best way to implement retry mechanism in aws lambda to handle network time out or other server side errors?

You can throw time out error further and don't handle it in your Lambda function, in this case your Lambda will be invoked again. Please note that it depends on configuration of your Lambda (i.e. number of retries set).
You can find more theory and practical examples [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/retries-on-errors.html).

> Also is it good to use retry inside lambda function, which cost as per execution time?

Lambda Retries are free for you (you pay only for Lambda execution and not for retry logic). Implementing your own retry approach inside Lambda is not free for you, because you pay for its execution.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. 
What about adding another lambda function, i.e. Main Lambda (say lambda-1) calls another lambda (say lambda-2) which interacts with external API. If external API fails with Timeout then lambda-2 throws that Timeout to lambda-1 and lambda-1 invokes lambda-2 again and again?
Another thing is if I continue to get timeout fron external API. How to stop retries after n time in lambda-1?

Answer (score 0):

1. You may increase the lambda execution time limiting.
2. You may track the execution time of the lambda, and when it close to limit, re-call your lambda with the same payload. I mean that lambda re-triggers itself until the external API would successfully response.
3. You can introduce SQS(Simple Queue System) to your system, where the messages for external API will be stored. And the some of consumer will send messages to external API. It may be an another lambda or some another running service which is responsible just for calling external API.